# syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Tags: php

```
<?php
session_start();
$link = mysqli_connect('remotemysql.com','3u5SxxxWnv','4VxvDT64ar','3u5SxxxWnv');
$login = md5($_POST['login']);
$pass =  md5($_POST['pass']);
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM form");

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  $_SESSION['user'] = (
      "id" => $user['id'],
      "login" => $user['login'],
      "email" => $user['email']
  );
} elseif(mysqli_num_rows($result) = 0) {
  $_SESSION['message'] = 'Не верный логин или пароль';
  header('location: /');
} else {
  header('location: /cob.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: `} else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Не верный логин или пароль';
    header('Location: ../index.php');
} // <<<<<< Лишняя скобка

} else {`

Comment: убрал , но все равно эта ошибка

Comment: в каком именно файле показывает эту ошибку (profile, index или cob) ? по идее или на экране или в логах должен показывать строчку в файле в котором ошибка

Comment: в cod показывает ошибку

Answer (score 1):

Массив должен создаваться при помощи квадратных скобок. В `elseif`, вероятно, задумывалось сравнение.

Вот пример валидной конструкции:

```php
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  $_SESSION['user'] = [ // замена скобки
      "id" => $user['id'],
      "login" => $user['login'],
      "email" => $user['email']
  ]; // замена скобки
}

elseif(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) { // = заменено на ==
  $_SESSION['message'] = 'Не верный логин или пароль';
  header('location: /');
}

else{
  header('location: /cob.php');
}
```

Cейчас же не понятно по какой логике выполнение должно пропустить первый `else` и перейти ко второму.

Comment: попробовал изменить , ничего не помогло , ошибка на 16 линии

Comment: Что именно было изменено?

Добавил валидный пример в ответ

Comment: изменил , но все равно ошибка , я поправил в вопросе

Comment: Массив должен создаваться при помощи квадратных скобок, а не круглых. 
`$_SESSION['user'] = [
/* данные */
];`

Так же, вероятно, пранировалсь сравнение 
`if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {}`
(обращаю внимание на количество знаков "равно")

Comment: оно не читает ни какие знаки

Comment: Можно конкретики на счёт того кто и что не читает? Изменил ответ в соответсвии с правками в вопросе